# How to stop other threads in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, executorservice

I made a client-server chat application and I get an imbalance of threads because I can only terminate one thread in my pool (2 threads).

For example, the server boots up. It creates one pool with two threads (one for sending, one for receiving). The server sends a message. It deletes the original thread for sending and creates a new pool. Now there is the original receiving thread and a new pool with two more threads. It does the same for the opposite story (receiving a message).

Both threads are stuck on waiting for an input or an output so I don't think I can do any check to see if the other thread is completed in the pool.

Code is something like this

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<String> send = executorService.submit(this::send);
Future<String> receive = executorService.submit(this::receive);

<some code to check to see if the future is completed>
sendComplete.cancel(true);
receiveComplete.cancel(true);
executorService.shutdownNow();

private void send() throws IOException {
        OutputStream os= socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(os, true);
********String msg= read.readLine(); //This is wear it freezes

        pw.println(messageOutput);
        pw.flush();
    }
```

The receive freezes up because of a similar line.

Is there a way to terminate/close all threads in an ExecutorService/pool? shutdownNow() does not work because the code in the thread is frozen/stuck on waiting for input/output.